# External HTML file in Django

Tags: html, django, external

I'm making Django app in which I need to embed many external HTML files in the template. Each HTML file is stored in its own directory, along with the subdirectory that contains all the images. The file structure:

```
Abstract1
    Pictures
        image1.png
        image2.png
   abstract1.html
```

I use a custom template tag for embedding (see below). My problem: the HTML files are loaded, but linked resources (e.g. img) are not working properly (i.e. they're not being displayed). HTML files use relative urls, which, mixed with the django template base path produce invalid url, but even if I use hardcoded absolute urls the problem remains. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Is there some proper (or not proper but working) way to overcome such problem?

**template**

```
{% load abstracts_extras %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="margin-left:10px">
        <h2>{{abstract}}</h2>
        <b>Authors:</b><br/>
        <ul>
            {% for author in authors %}
                <li>{{author}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <p>
        <b>Title: </b>{{abstract.title}}
        <p>
        <hr>

        {% include_external filename|add:'.html' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**abstracts_extras**

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

def include_external (url):
    url = 'file:///' + url
    import urllib2
    return urllib2.urlopen (url).read ()
```

Comment: I can't understand why your template tag is loading the external templates via urllib2 with a `file:///` URL, rather just opening them as local files.

Comment: I also can't understand what you're confused about; your static files need to be in a place that the static server will serve them from, and the URLs in the HTML need to point to the static URL.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding well, your templates load but not statics like img.
It would be a configuration error.
You should check both settings.py for Django and httpd.conf for Apache and check staticfiles are properly configured.
Have you any error shown or just images are not loaded (but no error)?

Comment: There is no error displayed. In the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
I'm using development server right now, so it's not Apache fault

Comment: why not ur are embedding external html links to a iframe and load it rather then doing using include_extras

Comment: Maybe you should check first testing this in your Django project to check your setting config. Then if you move it out of your project, I'm pretty sure you should write the path of your directories in settings.py in order to avoid 404.